# Javascript displaying output calculations

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to display the total hours worked lets say 40 then
    allowing to enter the hourly wage lets say 35.. and finally
    displaying 1400 which is the total..Can someone give a hand please.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <meta charset="utf-8">     <title>
    assignment3</title> <script type= "text/javascript"> <!--    var name;
    //string enterted by user
               var input;   //string enterted by user
               var hours;  //string enterted by user
               var payRate; //string enterted by user
               var grossPay; //string enterted by user

               // read the name

               name = window.prompt("What is your name?");   /*paranthesis missing and quotation marks misplaced */
               input = window.prompt("Enter the hours you worked."); 
               hours = ParseInt();

               input = window.prompt("Enter you hourly wage."); 
               payRate = ParseFloat();  

               grossPay = hours * payRate;

               //result
               document.writeln ("<h1> Hello" + name + " your gross pay is $" + grossPay+" <h1>");         
                    //-->        </script>   </head>     <body> </body>     </html>
```

Comment: `ParseInt();` or `ParseFloat()` should have arguments.

Comment: What this `hours = ParseInt();` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you're storing anything in `hours` or `payRate`. Try `hours = ParseInt(input);` and `payRate = ParseFloat(input);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the variable inside the ParseInt and ParseFloat, and JS is case-sensitive, fix your casing:

```
hours = parseInt(input);
```

Also, get in the habit of using "var" before every variable the first time you use it...or put var at the top to get in the habit of best-practices (not creating global variables).

```
var input;

var name = window.prompt("What is your name?");   /*paranthesis missing and var quotation marks misplaced */
input = window.prompt("Enter the hours you worked."); 
var hours = parseInt(input);

input = window.prompt("Enter you hourly wage."); 
var payRate = parseFloat(input);  

var grossPay = hours * payRate;

//result
document.writeln ("<h1> Hello" + name + " your gross pay is $" + grossPay+" <h1>");
```